# Adding new main menu item to Moodle Mobile 3.5

Tags: moodle, moodle-mobile

I am trying to develop a new plugin to add an item to the main menu more items in Moodle Mobile 3.5 using PHP and Angular/Ionic 3. I want to display a new main menu item "*Agenda*" with icon.

After creating the *db\mobile.php* file and define the delegate as "*CoreMainMenuDelegate*", the problem now is showing the name in the main menu as "*plugin.local_parentagenda.Agenda*", and without icon.

What can I try to resolve this?

- Moodle site version: 3.3.1
- Moodle Mobile version: 3.5

[image]

Comment: Do you did? Are you have repository these project? I'm problems to put a new item in the menu CoreMainMenuDelegate. "/

Answer (score 0):

You must add a valid key string from lang definition in displaydata as a title, and the icon is a string from [ionicicons](https://infinitered.github.io/ionicons-version-3-search). Search for ion-md, only those work. 

Here an example plugin local/example/db/mobile.php

```
$addons = array(
"local_example" => array( // Plugin identifier
    'handlers' => array( // Different places where the plugin will display content.
        'localexample' => array( // Handler unique name (alphanumeric).
            'displaydata' => array(
                'title' => 'pluginname',
                'icon' => 'bluetooth',
                'class' => '',
            ),

            'delegate' => 'CoreMainMenuDelegate', // Delegate (where to display the link to the plugin)
            'method' => 'mobile_test_view', // Main function in \local_example\output\mobile
        )
    ),
    'lang' => array(    // Language strings that are used in all the handlers.
        array('pluginname', 'local_example'),
        array('example:viewexample', 'local_example')
    ),
));
```

Note the title property in displaydata array and the pluginname definition in lang array, both are required.